# Reduce inference time of object detection model by retraining with subset of original dataset

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, google-coral

#newb

I'm using the [MobileNet SSD v2 (COCO) object detection model](https://coral.ai/models/) to detect trains from a live camera feed.

My goal is to reduce the inference time.

The COCO dataset is available [here](https://cocodataset.org/#explore) - there's 3745 annotated images of trains.

I'm using [this tutorial](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/retrain-detection/#configure-your-own-training-data) by Coral to retrain the mobilenet model.

So if I create a dataset using the train images from COCO and retrain this specific model, will the inference time be reduced? Or is creating a new model from scratch the only way?

Comment: I don't think you'll need another model as MobileNet is itself the fastest. Try quantizing the model or improving the preprocessing pipeline on the deployment platform ( i.e on Coral where you'll use the model for inference ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second @Shubham's answer, this won't make any difference in inference time, as long as you keep the input/output size the same.
After the retraining the model, you'll have a fully quantized tflite model, as long as you follow the tutorial and [compile](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/retrain-detection/#compile-the-model-for-the-edge-tpu) it for the edgetpu, you can expects similar results to this [benchmark](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/benchmarks/).

Comment: @shubham So I'm understanding that creating a completely separate model with just 3% of the original dataset will not reduce inference time?

Comment: By reducing the training dataset, are you also reducing the number of output classes?

Comment: Yes! There are 90 output classes for the original model, but I just need 1.

Comment: Ohhh I see, yes, theoretically should be much faster. Just like the [face detection](https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/blob/master/test_data/ssd_mobilenet_v2_face_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite) model that was built on the same mobilenet v2 that's performing much faster!